# php replace in array with custom replacement data

Tags: php, arrays, string

In this code as for example:

```
$hello=['aaaa','bbbb','cccc'];
$by=['1111','2222','3333'];
$data = "1111 aaaa cccc";
```

I want to replace `$by` with `$hello` with this custom replacement data for example:

```
str_replace( $hello , "<b>". $by . "</b>" , $data);
```

But I get array to string error. How can I use this custom replace method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to feed the arguments as an array in `str_replace`, by concatenating the string, it yields the error. You apply the bold text concatenation on the array replacement strings first, then you use the `str_replace`.

Here's the idea:

```
$by = array_map(function($e) {
    return "<b>{$e}</b>";
}, $by);
```

When you use it:

```
$hello=['aaaa','bbbb','cccc']; // needles
$by=['1111','2222','3333']; // replacements
$by = array_map(function($e) { // apply bold to replacements
    return "<b>{$e}</b>";
}, $by);
$data = "1111 aaaa cccc"; // haystack
$data = str_replace( $hello , $by, $data); // actual replacements
                //     ^ array  ^
```